# Can't bind to 'ngForFor' since it isn't a known property of 'li'

Tags: angular

My app.module

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { HttpModule } from '@angular/http';

import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { routing, appRoutingProviders} from './app.routing'
import { ProductSearchModule} from './productSearch/productSearch.module'

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    FormsModule,
    HttpModule,
    routing,
    ProductSearchModule
  ],
  providers: [appRoutingProviders],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

my productSearch.module

```
import {NgModule} from '@angular/core'
import {ProductSearchComponent} from './productSearch.component'

@NgModule({
    exports: [ProductSearchComponent],
    declarations: [ProductSearchComponent],

})

export class ProductSearchModule{}
```

my productSearch component

```
import { Component, Output } from '@angular/core'
import { Product} from '../shared/product'

@Component({
    selector: 'product-search',
    templateUrl: 'productSearch.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['productSearch.component.css'],

})

export class ProductSearchComponent{
    /**
     *
     */
    constructor() {
        var p1 = new Product;
        p1.name = "alkan";

        var p2 = new Product;
        p2.name = "alper";
        this.Products = [p1, p2];

    }

    Products: Product[]

    search(){

    }
}
```

productSearch.component.html file

```
<li *ngFor="let item for Products">{{item.name}}</li>
```

As you can see, this is a very basic example of Angular. I just want to print name of each product.

Error i'm getting:

> Can't bind to 'ngForFor' since it isn't a known property of 'li'.

**UPDATE:**

Component constructor changed as

```
var p1 = new Product();
p1.name = "alkan";

var p2 = new Product();
p2.name = "alper";
this.Products = [p1, p2];
```

and template html changed as

```
<li *ngFor="let item of Products">{{item.name}}</li>
```

But i still get error:

> ```
> Can't bind to 'ngForOf' since it isn't a known property of 'li'
> ```

Comment: should be `var p1=new Product(); & var p2=new Product();`

Comment: Could you please declare `Products: Product[]` this above of constructor?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

```
    var p1 = new Product();   //<----added ();
    p1.name = "alkan";

    var p2 = new Product();   //<----added ();
    p2.name = "alper";
    this.Products = [p1, p2];

     //<---replace for keyword by of keyword
    <li *ngFor="let item of Products">{{item.name}}</li>
```

**Update**

You also need to add ***CommonModule*** as shown below,

```
import {NgModule} from '@angular/core';   
import {ProductSearchComponent} from './productSearch.component'

import {CommonModule} from '@angular/common';

@NgModule({
    imports: [CommonModule],                   //<====added
    exports: [ProductSearchComponent],
    declarations: [ProductSearchComponent],

})
```

Comment: FYI. `commonmodule` contains all required directives like `*ngFor, *ngIf & etc`. You should use it with `featureModules ONLY`.

Comment: This would be better with some text explanation. I made the same mistake, and now I had to look in the code sample to see the comment explaining the thing. If only the solution had been there right above the code...

Comment: @Jasper I dont understand what are you saying?

Comment: @micronyks The key information in this answer is "you should write *ngFor="... of ..." not *ngFor="... for ...". It would be good if that information was at the top of the post instead of hidden in a code fragment.

Comment: import of common module is not required. It is the *ngFor syntax which should be `of` not `for`

Answer (score 48):

I think it's: `let item of Products` not `for` in the `productSearch.component.html` file.
Check the [documentation](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/common/index/NgFor-directive.html)